# Proof that $N$ is an immersed submanifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, solution-verification

Consider the following set in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$$N := \{(\cos(t),\sin(t),e^t) \rvert t \in \mathbb{R}\} \sqcup \{(\cos(t),\sin(t),0) \vert t \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$
This is the union of a 'spiral' and a circle. We have to show (or disprove) that this is an immersed submanifold.
Intuitively, I would guess this is indeed an immersed submanifold. We equip this with the topology whose opens are 'along' the spiral and the circle. Then, the inclusion is evidently smooth and furthermore the differential is injective. However, I'm not entirely sure if this is truly correct.

Comment: What are the open sets near the circle? Note that the spiral swirls around from above faster and faster until it limits to the unit circle in the xy-plane.

Comment: Relative to the topology I endowed the set with, being the topology 'along' the leaf, I would assume that the opens near the circle (but not ON the circle) are just pieces of the spiral? Or am I incorrect here

Comment: The open balls centered on the circle look like a bunch of arcs on the spiral limiting to an arc on the circle. In particular it is NOT an embedded submanifold. That's the subtlety the problem is trying to get at (but does that say anything about being an immersed submanifold?)

Comment: You mean the open balls with respect to the ambient topology right? Then yes, this is indeed the case (and therefore $N$ won't be an embedded submanifold). But I'm wondering if my topology yields it to be an immersed submanifold. In my topology, opens centered on the circle are just arcs of the circle itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An immersed submanifold of a manifold $M$ is the image $N = f(S)$ of an immersion $f: S \to M$ defined on a smooth manifold $S$. Note that in general $N$ is not a submanifold of $M$, even if $f$ is injective (which is in general not true).

So let $S = \mathbb R \times \{0,1\} \subset \mathbb R^2$. This is a smooth manifold (in fact, a smooth submanifld of $\mathbb R^2$). Define $f : S \to \mathbb R^3, f(t,0) = (\cos t, \sin t, e^t), f(t,1) = (\cos t, \sin t, 0)$. This is clearly an immersion with image $N$ as in your question. However, it is not a submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$.

Alternatively you can define $S = \mathbb R \times \{(0,1)\} \cup S^1 \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb R^3$, where $S^1 = \{ (x,y) \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$, and $f(t,0,1) = (\cos t, \sin t, e^t), f(p,0) = (p,0)$. Then $f$ is an injective immersion and its restrictions to $\mathbb R \times \{(0,1)\}$ and to $S^1 \times \{0\}$ are embeddings.